# Why is this error occuring when I am using filter in pandas: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

When I want to remove some elements which satisfy a particular condition, python is throwing up the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-93addf38c9f9> in <module>()
  4 
  5 df = pd.read_csv('fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv;
----> 6 df = filter(df,~('-02-29' in df['Date']))
  7 '''tmax = []; tmin = []
  8 for dates in df['Date']:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The following is the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv');
df = filter(df,~('-02-29' in df['Date']))
```

What wrong could I be doing?

Following is sample data

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw9pa.png)

Comment: Apparently the `Date` field contains integers, not strings. Can you show a sample of the CSV?

Comment: ID Date Element Data_Value
0 USW00094889 2014-11-12 TMAX 22
1 USC00208972 2009-04-29 TMIN 56
2 USC00200032 2008-05-26 TMAX 278
3 USC00205563 2005-11-11 TMAX 139
4 USC00200230 2014-02-27 TMAX -106

Comment: Note that your data file has slashes ( / ) within the date strings, but you are filtering with hyphens ( - ).

Answer (score 0):

Use df.filter() (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)
Also please attach the csv so we can run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use one of pandas' string methods for Boolean indexing:

```py
df = df[~ df['Date'].str.contains('-02-29')]
```

You will still have to make sure that all the dates are actually strings first.

**Edit:**
Seeing the picture of your data, maybe this is what you want (slashes instead of hyphens):

```py
df = df[~ df['Date'].str.contains('/02/29')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I want is to drop all the records which has date of 29-02 as it is part of the leap year

Comment: @Saif Mehdi yes, and that's exactly what the code above is designed to do, isn't it? Dropping the rows which contain 29-02 is the same as keeping the rows that don't, or am I missing something?